# Drop null rows from a column that has a dynamic name

Tags: apache-spark-sql

How do I drop null rows from a column name that's dynamic?

It's dynamic because the only column in this table is from a UDF and it's a temporary view.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW temp_table
AS
SELECT udf1(input)
FROM input_table;
```

So the temporary view will look something like

```
|UDF:udf1(some input)|
|--------------------|
|         1          |
|         2          |
|         null       |
 --------------------
```

I want to drop all null rows, so the temporary view looks like

```
|UDF:udf1(some input)|
|--------------------|
|         1          |
|         2          |
 --------------------
```

I've been trying something like

```
DELETE FROM temp_table
WHERE ??? IS NULL;
```

but it seems like the column name isn't static...and I've been looking at `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` but my sql isn't recognizing such a view. I also looked at trying to do something like `drop from table where 'column that starts with UDF' is null` but apparently that's not allowed either

Comment: SELECT udf_col FROM (SELECT udf1(input) as udf_col
FROM input_table)T WHERE udf_col IS NOT NULL

Comment: You can try above query inside your create temp view statement.